# Combining Multiple String Commands Into One Line

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm using PowerShell and running a tool to extract Lenovo hardware RAID controller info to identify the controller number for use later on in another command line (this is part of a SCCM Server Build Task Sequence).  The tool outputs a lot of data and I'm trying to isolate just what I need from the output.

I've been able to isolate what I need, but I'm thinking there has to be a more efficient way so looking for optimizations.  I'm still learning when it comes to working with strings.

The line output from the tool that I'm looking for looks like this:

```
0 0   0   252:0    17  DRIVE Onln  N  557.861 GB dsbl N  N   dflt -
```

I'm trying to get the 3 characters to the left of the :0 (the 252 but on other models this could be 65 or some other 2 or 3 digit number)

My existing code is:

```
$ControllerInfo = cmd /c '<path>\storcli64.exe /c0 show'

$forEach ($line in $ControllerInfo) {
    if ($line -like '*:0 *') {
        $ControllerNum = $line.split(':')[0]  # Get everything left of :
        $ControllerNum = $ControllerNum.Substring($ControllerNum.Length -3)  # Get last 3 chars of string
        $ControllerNum = $ControllerNum.Replace(' ', '')  # Remove blanks
        Write-Host $ControllerNum
        break  #stop looping through output
    }
}
```

The above works but I'm wondering if there's a way to combine the three lines that start with $ControllerNum = so I can have just have a single $ControllerNum = (commands) line to set the variable instead of doing it in 3 lines.  Basically want to combine the Split, Substring and Replace commands into a single line.

Thanks!

Comment: What about regex?  `"0 0    0   252:0  ..." .match "(\S*):"`; `"matches[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
$ControllerNum = ([regex]'(\d{2,3}):0').Match($line).Groups[1].Value
```

Used on your sample `0 0   0   252:0    17  DRIVE Onln  N  557.861 GB dsbl N  N   dflt -`

the result in $ControllerNum wil be `252`

Comment: thank-you for the quick response!  This worked perfectly.  Much appreciated!

Comment: One follow-up question.  If I wanted the 557.861  before GB as the deliminator, how would you do something similar?

Comment: @Jeff For that, you could use `$DiskSize = ([regex]'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) GB').Match($line).Groups[1].Value`. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the last digits before the first `:`, without any whitespace, you can do that with one or two regex expressions:

```
$line -replace '^.*\b(\d+):.*$','$1'
```

Regex explanation:

```
^       # start of string
 .*     # any number of any characters
 \b     # word boundary
 (      # start capture group
  \d+   # 1 or more strings
 )      # end capture group
 :      # a literal colon (:)
 .*     # any number of any characters
$       # end of string
```

replacement:

```
$1      # Value captured in the capture group above
```